# What's this OLD C pointer-math / macro thing doing?

Tags: c, pointers, macros, b-tree, isam

I need help trying to understand what's happening in some old C code.

I'm utilizing an old btree/isam software product (from Softfocus) to write my data to the database. It essentially puts data into a `mydb.dt` file and the index data into `mydb.nx` (for example).

In my program, I have a struct with members corresponding to "fields" in the database. The struct is defined like so (I'm greatly simplifying with fictional data):

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char name[50];    /*size is 50 bytes*/
    int active;                /*size is 4 bytes*/
    int yet_unused_bytes[46];  /*unused space (in fixed-length record)*/
} DB_PEOPLE;                   /*total struct size is 100 bytes*/
```

When I want to write to the record, I call the DB software's `bt3Write` routine like so (`people_db_fd` is my database-file's descriptor, and `db_current_record_people` is just a copy of my struct above, with data in it):

```
ret = bt3Write(people_db_fd, db_current_record_people);
```

That `bt3Write` routine is basically the following (I don't think it's important to know exactly what it's doing, but the key part is the trueBase bit). The `fd` is the database file, and `data` is the byte stream (the `db_current_record_people` struct that I'm handing to it above). I suppose `recno` is just some overhead for the nx file that I don't care about here, that `lioWrite` takes care of:

```
/*
 * all the keys are in; write the data record and store a copy
 */
if (lioWrite(fd -> fdData, recno, trueBase(data)) == UERROR)
    return (sfuint) isMuCallErr(BT3WRITE, 0);
```

In a header file, `trueBase` and `BASEOFFSET` are defined as the following macros:

```
/*
 *  macro for easing the buffer address calculations (who knows what
 *  may change down the road
 */
#define  BASEOFFSET             (sizeof(sflong))
#define  trueBase(address)      ((char *) address - BASEOFFSET)
```

Now, here's what I would like help with (I'm by no means a C expert... barely functional, really). I need to know what trueBase is doing (or your best guess). To my untrained eye, it seems like it's shifting the pointer to the data by the length of BASEOFFSET (which is 8 bytes on my system).

Extra bonus points for anyone who knows anything about this particular software product, too! It's pretty old, and I can't really find ANY documentation for it. It's commented fairly well - except for this bit.

Comment: How is `sflong` defined?

Comment: @Codor... in my case, 8 bytes.

Comment: This is probably just an irrelevant typo, but `int unused[46]` almost certainly uses more than 46 bytes. You probably meant `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. It looks as if they are storing some hidden header data in each allocation that they are doing. So they only give you a pointer to the "user" part. Only when you have to `free` the data, for example, you need to know the "real" starting point of the allocated space and that's what the macro is computing.

I don't apply for the extra point since I have no idea what that is.

Comment: So, do you think I can take that to mean: I can do whatever I like with the data, and as long as I hand `lioWrite` its `trueBase` value, I should be alright.

I looked into `lioWrite` and it's essentially distilling down into a stock C `write` call... I'm assuming the hidden header data is just the linkage to the corresponding index in the `.nx` file.

Comment: You'd have to be pretty sure that everybody interprets it the same way, and that you exactly know the size of the data that you have to `write`. But I guess running things in a debugger (or valgrind) tells you that you are neither missing data to write, nor overwriting memory that you shouldn't. Reverse engineering is a difficult art :(

Comment: Your insight is helpful, thanks! I'll also add the following... my structure is 100 bytes, but I'm noticing that the data size in bt3Write shows 108 bytes. It's adding 8 bytes to the end, actually. I wonder if this is a pre-reserved space for the next record's header data. I'd appreciate your guess.